# Como implementar roles en mi aplicacion web

Tags: php, mysql, modelorelacional

Buenas soy nuevo aqui tengo una duda con un sistema de autenticacion que requiere roles,tengo una tabla users relacionada con los otros tipos de usuario pero  no se como implementarlo si una tabla para cada tipo de usuario(conductor,pasajero) como lo muestra la imagen  o dos tablas usuarios y roles, pero como diferencio la relacion que hay entre por ejemplo un pasajero que hace una solicitud de carrera, si todo seria una sola tabla con conductor estoy implemetando este modelo en yii.

agradezco quien pueda orientarme un poco.
[image: Modelo Relacional]

Comment: dos tablas: usuarios y roles; la forma de diferenciarlo es por el id de la tabla respectiva; es decir si un usuario es pasajero puede hacer una petici´pon y cuando la haga se guarda el id de su tipo de usuario para que después mediante consultas identifiques su rol de usuario

Comment: comprendo entonces esa parte pero me queda una gran duda como relaciono por ejemplo la tabla conductor, (que seria ahora un tipo de usuario )con vehículo y pasajero(ahora en tabla tipo usuario) con una solicitud de carrera ? podrias ser mas detallado